# Verilog code error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have been trying to run this Verilog code which simulates traffic decongestion, but I am getting this error. I have also tried to use an `always` block, but I am still not able to resolve it. Following are my design and testbench files in that order.

```vhdl
// main module

module test2(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, h, l, lane_no);

input v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, h, l;
output[1 : 0] lane_no;

wire local;
wire x1, x2, p;
wire e3, e2, e1;

assign local = v1 & v2 & v3;
wire[2 : 0] count1 = 3'b000;
wire[2 : 0] count2 = 3'b000;

wire a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3;
assign a1 = count1[0];
assign a2 = count1[1];
assign a3 = count1[2];
assign b1 = count2[0];
assign b2 = count2[1];
assign b3 = count2[2];

if (local) begin      // This is Line 26 (see error messages)
    assign lane_no = 2'b11;
end
else
begin
    assign e3 = ~(a3^b3);
    assign e2 = ~(a2^~b2);
    assign e1 = ~(a1^~b1);
    assign x1 = (~a3 & b3) + (e3 & ~a2 & b2) + (e3 & e2 & ~a1 & b1);
    assign x2 = ~x1;
    assign p = e3 & e2 & e1;

    if (p == 1)
    begin
        if (count1 == 3'b000)
        begin
            assign lane_no = 2'b01;
            assign count1 = count1 + 3'b001;
            assign count1 = count1 - 3'b001;
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

I am getting this error when I execute the following command:

```
harshal@dl8-OptiPlex-9010:~/Desktop$ iverilog test.v testbench.v 
test.v:26: error: Unable to bind parameter `local' in `main.dut'
test.v:26: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: 
local
test.v:26: error: Unable to bind parameter `local' in `main.dut'
test.v:26: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: 
local
4 error(s) during elaboration.
```

```vhdl
module main;
    reg v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,h,l;
    wire[2:0] lane_no;
    test2 dut(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,h,l,lane_no);
    
    initial begin
        v1=1;v2=1;v3=1;v4=0;v5=0;h=1;l=0;
        #10 v1=1;v2=0;v3=1;v4=0;v5=0;h=1;l=0;
        #10 v1=1;v2=1;v3=0;v4=0;v5=0;h=0;l=1;
    end

    initial begin
        $monitor("  output= %b%b%b",lane_no);
    end
endmodule
```

I am not able to figure out the exact error as I am beginner in Verilog programming.

Comment: Can you add the code with always block and error messages for the code with always block?

Answer (score 2):

When the Verilog compiler sees an `if/else` which is not inside an `always` block, it assumes the code is a `generate` construct.  It expects the `if` conditional expression to be a constant, which means it expects `local` to be a `parameter`, for example.  However, you declared `local` to be a variable type (`wire`).  This explains the error message you received.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27. *Generate constructs*.

It is possible to place the `if/else` code inside an `always` block, but other changes are needed as well.  All signals assigned inside the `always` procedural block should be declared as `reg`, not `wire`.  Also, there is no need for the `assign` keyword in the `always` block.

```
module test2(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,h,l,lane_no);
   input v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,h,l;
   output reg [1:0] lane_no;
   wire             local;
   reg              x1,x2,p;
   reg              e3,e2,e1;

   assign local=v1&v2&v3;
   reg [2:0]        count1=3'b000;
   reg [2:0]        count2=3'b000;

   wire             a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3;
   assign a1=count1[0];
   assign a2=count1[1];
   assign a3=count1[2];

   assign b1=count2[0];
   assign b2=count2[1];
   assign b3=count2[2];

   always @* begin
      if(local) begin
         lane_no= 2'b11;
      end else
        begin
           e3=~(a3^b3);
           e2=~(a2^~b2);
           e1=~(a1^~b1);

           x1=(~a3&b3)+(e3&~a2&b2)+(e3&e2&~a1&b1);
           x2=~x1;
           p=e3&e2&e1;
           if(p==1) begin
              if(count1==3'b000)
                begin
                   lane_no=2'b01;
                   count1=count1+3'b001;
                   count1=count1-3'b001;
                end
           end
        end
   end
endmodule
```

I used `emacs` Verilog-mode to reformat the code using reasonable indentation.

This code compiles without errors for `iverilog`.

---

Note that `local` is now a keyword for SystemVerilog (IEEE Std 1800).  Apparently, it has not yet been implemented with `iverilog`, but I recommend you change `local` to something else like `local1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the use of `if-else` statements otside of a procedural block (`always`, etc).

Your code below will not work:

```
if(local) begin 
assign lane_no= 2'b11;
end

else
begin

assign e3=~(a3^b3);
...
```

You need to think about what the code will describe in terms of hardware, as this is not a programming language, but a hardware description language.

Here you say "if signal local is high, add some circuitry to set `lane_no`. Otherwise, remove that circuitry and add some other circuitry to assign `e3` etc.". This can't work because the hardware must be fixed once synthesis is complete - you can't suddenly add extra circuitry at run time.

To use `if-else` you should switch to using `always` blocks and `=`/`<=` rather than `assign` (note that this will require the target variables to be `reg` rather than `wire`):

```
reg x;
always @ (trigger) begin
    if (condition) begin
        x <= val_if_true;
    end else begin
        x <= val_if_false;
    end
end
```

In other cases you can use the ternary operator with `assign` statements if appropriate:

```
assign x = (condition) ? val_if_true : val_if_false;
```

---

I would suggest going back to basics and finding a tutorial on how to program in Verilog. [This](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day1.html#Introduction) is one that I found quite useful way back when I was learning Verilog.